# converting svg to pdf returning empty pdf file

Tags: canvas, svg, plotly, jspdf, html2canvas

I am working from the following example:
http://jsfiddle.net/p4s5k59s/1222/

Trying to convert a plotly.js svg element into a pdf image/file.

Controller function:

```
  $scope.savePdf = function(){
    html2canvas($("#graphRender"), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {   
        console.log(canvas);      
            var imgData = canvas.toDataURL(
                'image/png');              
            var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
            doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 1000, 1000);
            doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
        }
    });
  }
```

HTML:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using jsPDF and html2canvas just to be clear about libraries. jsPDF has although really bad documentation so I see where this is coming from. Important method here is

> .addImage() method

Which has syntax like this:

> addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);

Try playing a bit with your code to get the position right and then adjust the width and hight you want to have in PDF. You can even try it on plunker you've provided, just replace the method with this one to get different output:

> doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 10, 200, 300);

Then I think you will see the point and make it work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The thing is that if I target the div with `id="graphRender"` or the svg element, the resulting image is just white/empty. If instead I target the whole `document.body` than everything appears by exception of the svg/plot